# How have i to import correctly jszip for DevExtreme Export in an Angularjs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, devextreme, jszip

i'm new to angularjs and require,  how have i to load correctly the jszip library in an environment with DevExtreme and AngularJS? i have tried different ways but get always an error. My structure is made on this way:

```
require.config({
...
paths: {
    'controller.home' : extensionRoot + 'controllers/home',
    'controller.dashboard' : extensionRoot + 'controllers/dashboard',
    'controller.analisi' : extensionRoot + 'controllers/analisi'
    'domReady' : extensionRoot + 'js/vendor/domReady/domReady',
    'app' : extensionRoot + 'js/app.min',
    'slider' : extensionRoot + 'js/vendor/angularjs-slider/dist/rzslider',
    'angular-bootstrap': extensionRoot + 'js/vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min',
    'jszip' : extensionRoot + 'js/vendor/devexpress/js/jszip',
    'dx' : extensionRoot + 'js/vendor/devexpress/js/dx.all'
}})                                                        
define(['require',
    'angular',
    'slider',
    'angular-bootstrap',
    'dx'
    ], function(require, angular) {
'use strict';

angularRoutingApp = angular.module('angularRoutingApp', ['ngRoute', 'rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap','dx']);
```

If i have the script in this way get the error:
The JSZip script is referenced after DevExtreme scripts

instead if try to load the library following DevExtreme like on this link:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Getting_Started/Installation/Local_Scripts/
 i get the error:
Mismatched anonymous define() module

Thanks

Comment: Read that site: `NOTE
Reference the jszip.min.js script before the DevExtreme scripts.`.

Comment: i read that info and i have tried to put the reference of jszip before dx, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about AngularJS and not Angular2 right?

If that is the case just go to your file *index.html* that you have in the root of your application.

Once there just add your references this way

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dx.all.js"></script>
```

An that's all since your views will run within this index page (because you are using a SPA framework), you are ready at this point, if you are using **Angular2** it is totally **different**.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the fact that the OP is using RequireJS.